# How to mount specific /proc for all Docker containers on a host?

Tags: docker, lxd

I am running Docker containers within an LXD container and I have noticed that Docker mounts it's own copy of `/proc` despite the LXD container having container-aware `/proc` files.

For example:

```
root@lxdcontainer:~# grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo 
1
root@lxdcontainer:~# grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:         488280 kB
root@lxdcontainer:~# docker run -it ubuntu bash 
root@fcd00479a2c1:/# grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo 
56
root@fcd00479a2c1:/# grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       263758600 kB
```

As you can see above, the LXD container has been allocated 1 CPU core and about 500MB of memory. However, a Docker container that is run inside this LXD container seems to think it has access to all 56 cores and 256GB of memory on the bare metal host.

I have tried using [LXCFS](https://github.com/lxc/lxcfs) as shown below:

```
docker run -it \
    -v /var/lib/lxcfs/proc/cpuinfo:/proc/cpuinfo:rw \
    -v /var/lib/lxcfs/proc/diskstats:/proc/diskstats:rw \
    -v /var/lib/lxcfs/proc/meminfo:/proc/meminfo:rw \
    -v /var/lib/lxcfs/proc/stat:/proc/stat:rw \
    -v /var/lib/lxcfs/proc/swaps:/proc/swaps:rw \
    -v /var/lib/lxcfs/proc/uptime:/proc/uptime:rw \
    ubuntu:18.04 \
    bash
```

This has worked and the Docker container shows the CPU and memory resources that have been allocated to the LXD container. However, this needs to be manually specified for each Docker container that is launched and this is not feasible when Docker containers are automatically launched (for example, when [creating nodes for a custom cluster in Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-provisioning/rke-clusters/custom-nodes/)).

My goal is to get all Docker containers running in the LXD container to only see resources that have been allocated to the LXD container and nothing else. Please let me know how I can do so.